# Resistance and permittivity

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

I saw this formula in a book
RC =  ρε
Can anyone tell me what is the significance of this formula or how is it derived? 
The capacitance and the resistivity seem to be pretty much unrelated quantities but there seems to be a straightforward relationship between them.
When and where can I use this formula?

Comment: The capacitance and resistivity *are* unrelated; the relationship is between (1) a component's resistance and the constitutive material's resistivity and (2) a component's capacitance and the constitutive dielectric's permittivity. These relationships are also mediated by the geometry, but presumably for a given geometry, the geometric factors (specifically, L/A for the resistance and A/d for the capacitance) can be made to cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

$R$ is given by: 
$$
R = \rho \frac{d}{A}
$$
and $C$  by:
$$
C = \epsilon \frac{A}{d}
$$

Multiplying $R$ and $C$ gives us:
$$
RC = \rho \epsilon
$$

Capacitance and resistivity are unrelated, like Chemomechanics pointed out.

Comment: This shows it's true for a particular geometry (namely, parallel plates).  However, I believe the result can be extended to any two electrodes of any geometry surrounded by a medium of resistivity $\rho$ and permittivity $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Think your question this way: You have a pipe and inside the pipe you have rocks randomly placed.Once you push one ball inside the pipe it will encounter the rocks and will scatter.
The bigger the pipe is , the more balls you can push inside , without touching each other.
And the wider the pipe is , the more rocks the balls will encounter , so those rocks will resist the movement of the balls from one end to another.